# Calculate average speed in Powerbi using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data from 2 cameras: car number, camera, date_time. Camera A is the first, B - second camera.

I need to calculate the average speed for cars that have passed both cameras and the passage time is at least 5 min and no more than 30 min. The distance between the cameras is 6 km.

I counted only the nearest car crossing times for the same car. I couldn't find the camera B crossing time for the nearest A crossing time.

```
Diff_time = 
VAR temp =
    TOPN (
        1;
        FILTER (
            'TEST2';
            'TEST2'[license_plate] = EARLIER ( 'TEST2'[license_plate])
                && 'TEST2'[Date_time] < EARLIER ( 'TEST2'[Date_time] ) 
        );
        'TEST2'[Date_time]; DESC
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( MINX ( temp; 'TEST2'[Date_time] ); 'TEST2'[Date_time]; MINUTE )
```

[license_plate] is car number.

[example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtDxD.png)

[image]

Comment: it would be helfull if you 1) include example of desired outcome; 2) add data sample in text format

Comment: The DAX formula, written by Marco Vos, works fine, but not with all the data. Is it possible to solve this problem by writing a query in the SQL database?

Comment: 1) example of desired outcome is in the Marcos's answer; 2) I am a new member here. I can't find where I can place my data CSV file :(.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a table that looks something like this:

[image]

then a DAX-expression like this will create the calculated Column [MIN_diff_Minutes_with_Camera A]. For rows with Camera B it returns the smallest difference in minutes with a DT_stamp from camera A that is smaller then the DT in that row, refers to the same car and is between 5 and 30 minutes. For rows with Camera A it returns a blank.

```
MIN_diff_Minutes_with_Camera A =
VAR DT_camera_A =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( TEST2[DT_Stamp] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( TEST2, TEST2[Car] ),
        'TEST2'[Camera] = "A",
        'TEST2'[DT_Stamp] < EARLIER ( TEST2[DT_Stamp] )
    )
VAR Time_Diff_in_Minutes =
    DATEDIFF ( DT_camera_A, 'TEST2'[DT_Stamp], MINUTE )
RETURN
    IF (
        'TEST2'[Camera] = "B"
            && TIme_Diff_in_Minutes >= 5
            && Time_Diff_in_Minutes <= 30,
        Time_Diff_in_Minutes, --For avg speed in km/h use: 6*(Time_Diff_in_Minutes/60)
        BLANK ()
    )
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It works perfectly. But there is another problem - when I analyze all the records - 900k - shows error - not enough memory. Everything works well if I reduce the number of records to 120k. I make calculations on a virtual server with 110GB of RAM. Maybe there is some BI set for memory usage? Or can I reduce the number of entries by filtering only those cars that have "A" and "B" records using the CALCULATETABLE function?

Comment: I tried to reduce the number of records this way: I made a first table with A camera values, then made a second table with B camera values. I made the third table - I added Table B values ​​that match the cars in Table A. Then I deleted the A values ​​in this table and left only the B values. I made the fourth table - I added a third table to the first table and applied the formula you wrote. Is the Right Way?

Comment: To reduce the amount of search data in the DAX formula, is it possible to look up the value of the B camera no later than 24 hours?